# Django: AttributeError when calling own model method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I recently added a new method to my model "News":

```
def slug(self):
    return slugify(self.title)
```

However I can't seem to call it from anywhere. Imagine I have a News object called n. When trying to call

```
n.slug()
```

I always get an error like:

```
AttributeError: 'News' object has no attribute 'slug'
```

I'm a total beginner at Django and Python and I'm sure this is just a stupid mistake on my side. By the way I tried restarting the dev server and syncing the db after I added the method, both don't change a thing. Note that I have used model methods like this before without a problem :S

**Edit:**

Here is the model:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    [...]
    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.title)
```

Here is some example code on how I call the method. I first tried to call it in a template, but it didn't work. Then I changed my view so it just returns the slug, but the error remains. Same when I try it in the shell.

```
from fbki.models import News

def news_detail(request, slug, news_id):
    news = News.objects.get(id = news_id)
    return HttpResponse(news.slug())
```

Comment: Can you post the model that slug if a part of and the code where you make the call to `slug()`

Comment: Agree with Timmy, we don't have enough information now to answer your question.

Comment: I can't see where you instance news. You need to do 

news = News.objects.get(pk=news_id)

Comment: Sorry yeah forgot that line :S Already edited in 10 seconds later.

Comment: Hmmm, I think everything looks ok. Maybe you should try clearing your `.pyc` files: `find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -r {} \;` (or manually delete the `models.pyc` for the `News` model

Comment: Could there be an indentation error? Maybe you have used tabs instead of spaces somewhere, as a result of which Python isn't seeing the `slug` method as part of the class?

Comment: Also check if it works from Python console:

>>> News().slug()

Answer (score 0):

There are, no errors. Please check what class you by

```
  from fbki.models import News
```

it looks like you have two copies in project, and modify other class. You check by renaming your class News to News1. It you will same error - I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some errors similar to this.

I believe that the problem is an inconsistency between your model and the actual schema in your database.

Run `manage.py sql myapp` and verify the contents match what is in sql> show schema (etc.)

If they don't match, you have to use your SQL client and drop the old table so that you can re-run `manage.py syncdb` to make them match again.

Your method should work once the schema are present.